# Can you create a deeplink into a downloaded html5 webapp

Tags: html, web-applications, deep-linking

I want to be able to send a user an email or text with an embedded url which would open a locally installed html5 webapp.  Currently the embedded urls open the html5 webapp inside a browser.  It works but is not ideal.

Comment: Where else would you expect a link to open if not in the web browser? In the email reader itself? Good luck with that. I wouldn't know an email reader which is insane enough to execute javascript.

Comment: You don't understand the question.  I want it to launch the webapp not the browser.  Just like if you receive an email with a facebook link, it can open in the facebook native app, if you have the app installed.

Comment: Do you want to [register an URL schema protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) so links with that protocol specifier launch a specific program?